# Should I use XHTML/CSS2 or HTML5/CSS3 on my blog project?

Tags: html, frameworks, css

I'm going to develop a theme for a WordPress blog but I'm not sure if I should do it using XHTML/CSS2 or if I already can do it using HTML5/CSS3.

Usually, I use 960.gs framework but it isn't available with HTML5/CSS3. I've heard that the 52framework works fine as well and I'm thinking about adopt it for my project, but I'm really insecure about HTML5's early adoption (?).

Someone, please, can help me to decide which technology adopt on my project.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Newbie: What Should I Learn First (HTML & CSS) Or (HTML5 & CSS3)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912430/newbie-what-should-i-learn-first-html-css-or-html5-css3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 and CSS3 are "ready to use" - you need to learn a little about the concept of "Polyfilling", but you can make the user experience very similar in all browsers, even if you lose a few transition effects and rounded corners along the way.

My website has been HTML5 since 2009 and I tested it across many, many browsers.

So the bottom line is, HTML5 is designed to be highly backwards compatible with HTML4.01 and there are lots of techniques for making content available to older browsers that don't support the more funky elements in HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

The 960 grid system will work with HTML5 and CSS3 because it's just a list of classes. CSS3 doesn't really give you any grid layout features yet that are widely adopted enough to be helpful.

I would use CSS3 and HTML5 as much as you can but don't forget about progressive enhancement. Don't blindly ignore a browser because it doesn't support CSS3. You should use HTML5 and CSS3 appropriately and not because it's cool.

Answer (score 1):

What audience are you designing it for? Do you need to be bleeding edge?

I would say use XHTML/CSS2 as that will be supported for years unless you need the functionality in the others.

Being an early adopter can be quite painful, so only do that if you have good reasons to.

Comment: I don't need design anything special that requires HTML5, but I'm considering it just to be up to dated with new technologies, once I hope my blog will exists for a long time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Html5 and css3 for sure!

The only thing you might want to ask yourself is wether or not you want to use the new elements (article, aside, nav etc.)  Because if you do, you need to depend on Javascript in order for IE to render your page correctly.

Every new page should be written with the new doctype imo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If you want a starting template that works well in all major browsers you might want to check this out: http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: There is a non-JavaScript shim for HTML5 also - in case you don't want to use the HTML5 version. http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201012/Blog/HTML-5-Without-JavaScript-Shims/

Comment: But, that is cheating. Really. Using a div wrapper with the same class name as the html5 elements is not the same thing as using the html5 elements directly.

Comment: Agreed - I actually prefer to use the JS shim, but you don't have to use one in order to benefit from using more semantic mark-up.

Answer (score 1):

Whole-heartedly agree with Bravax.

It's all really based on who your audience is. If you want your site to be on the bleeding edge, regardless of audience, go for it.

I have heard **great** things about [52framework](http://www.52framework.com/)! I am about to implement it into a full-on 100+ page site redesign. The good thing about it, is that it plays nice with IE (even 6!).

Comment: Do you know 960.gs? The 52framework works fine like 960.gs? I've developed some projects with 960.gs and enjoyed it a lot.

Comment: I'm still learning the ropes of 960, but what I've used of it I've enjoyed :) 52framework, from my understanding of it, is actually a way to develop your HTML5/CSS3 without worrying about what to do with it in browsers that don't fully support HTML5/CSS3. The great thing about 52, IMO, is that you can pick & choose what you want to use: it comes with a grid.css, but if you'd rather use 960.gs, I don't think it'd interfere with anything else from 52's stuff.

Answer (score -1):

It is entirely related to the markets you are aiming at. You will be able to have more interactive content and easier to maintain styles with CSS3. This said, many of the html5 and css3 elements are not yet standardized. Even among the modern, cutting-edge, browsers there can be major differences.

If you are making a theme for experimental purposes or to play around with, I would go with the newer technologies.

If you are making this for consumption on a wide sale, and potential sale, you really should avoid technologies not supported by older browers, IE 7 and 8 especially.

Comment: HTML5 and CSS3 can both work with IE7 (and IE6) for that matter. There are plenty of poly-filling techniques to make your pages work for everyone. The argument against HTML5 was valid a while back, but it really isn't any longer.